# How to set up proxy with authentification in CefSharp chromiumwebbrowser?

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

I use CefSharp and https/socks proxy with login/password.

How can I set up proxy with authtentification for each instance of chromiumwebbrowser?

Now I'm using this code for setting proxy without auth.

```
wait Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            var rc = _browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
            rc.GetAllPreferences(true);
            var v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";

            string resProtocol = protocol == "https" ? "http" : protocol;

            //!!! sometimes its important to change PROTOCOL
            // I pointed http protocol for https proxy
            v["server"] = $"{resProtocol}://{_proxyIP}:{_proxyPort}";
            string error;
            bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);

            
        });
```

I tried different way but have not found one that works.
Important moment is I need to change proxy during work of application.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-authentication

Comment: @amaitland yes, it works!